# Best practice for double coordinates for Point

Tags: c#, wpf, double, point

There is `System.Drawing.Point` which accepts `int` values for `X` and `Y` coordinate paramenters.
This is **not** what I need.

Then there is `System.Windows.Point` which accepts `double` values for `X` and `Y`. This is what I'd need, however I am not sure if this is the structure I should be using in a class library project.

Lastly, I found `System.Drawing.PointF`, but it accepts `float` values for `X` and `Y` coordinate parameters. I'd prefer to use `double`.

What is the best practice?

#### Further clarification:

Basically, I have a WPF project and a Class Library project, which serves as a model to the UI. I need to remember Rectangle coodinates (double, double) in the model.

Comment: Where do you intend to use them?  The classes you mention exist (presumably) because they correspond to the types that those APIs need.  If you're doing your own thing, can't you just define your own?

Comment: My intention was not to define something when there is more than one option out there. Basically, I have a WPF project and a Class Library project, which serves as a model to the UI. I need to remember `Rectangle` coodinates (`double, double)` in the model.

Comment: Another advantage of using your own class is that you can convert to/from other classes as you need to.  If you need a Point class in your model, you do not require the dependency to a graphical library from the Framework.  In other words, it improves decoupling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not use anything else from `System.Drawing` or `System.Windows` implement your own `PointD` which uses double values. I also did that in a previous project... shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: And if you need it to be compatible with `PointF` or `Point`, you could always make it inherit those with the appropriate trunction/rounding logic as it fits your needs.

Comment: @JeffBridgman late to the show, but just want to point out that those are Structs and cannot be inherited.

Answer (score 3):

If you use GDI+ (the native API behind `System.Drawing`, used a lot in Windows Forms), you have to use `System.Drawing.Point` or `System.Drawing.PointF`. `System.Windows.Point` is only used in WPF. So there isn't a "best practice", it all depends on what type of application you want to create.

If you need a point structure for needs unrelated to either WPF or GDI+, create your own structure.

Comment: While the GDI+ types force a dependency on the GDI+ library, `System.Drawing.dll`, the dependency implications of `System.Windows.Point` are slightly less strong: Microsoft put that type in `WindowsBase.dll` to enable you to use it without taking a dependency on WPF (which is in `PresentationCore.dll` and `PresentationFramework.dll`).

Comment: @IanGriffiths, strictly speaking, you're correct, but I'm not sure what you would do with just WindowsBase.dll... I don't think it's used by anything but WPF.

Comment: I updated the question a bit. What I need is to remember `Rectangle` coordinates from WPF project in my Class Library model project.

Comment: I've used just `WindowsBase.dll` in several projects for precisely this reason - I wanted `Point` and `Rect` (including some of the related utility functions). It was all for internal use, so the dependencies we took didn't really affect anyone else, but as it happens, we ended up using `WindowsBase` and not WPF. so it can and does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vector2 (*System.Numerics*) where you can cast the double values to float (where casting to int obviously makes you lose the decimals).